# Converting dates in a CSV file into Seasons?

Tags: mongodb

I'm very new to MongoDB and clear with the basics but got stuck at a point.

I'm working in MongoDB with a CSV file. In it, there's a column called 'Issue Date'. Some dates are represented as `MM/DD/YYYY`, the others as `MM-DD-YYYY`. I read in the [documentations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) that MongoDB accepts the hyphen format(?). I don't know if I'm in the right direction, though.

Then, I have to divide them all into [Seasons](https://www.nyc.com/visitor_guide/weather_facts.75835/) for NYC.

The CSV can be found [here](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/Parking-Violations-Issued-Fiscal-Year-2020/pvqr-7yc4)

Comment: How do you define a season? The link you provide is about NYC only. Seasons are different in Sydney. And some parts of the world only have dry and wet seasons.

Comment: The csv is for NYC, so the seasons are by extension, for NYC too :)